# 404 when closing pull request on github api

Tags: python, github, github-api

I have the following code for interacting with pull requests on the github api.

```
def merge(pull):
  url = "https://api.github.com/repos/{}/{}/pulls/{}/merge".format(os.environ.get("GITHUB_USERNAME"), os.environ.get("GITHUB_REPO"), pull['number'])
  response = requests.put(url, auth=get_auth(), data={})
  if response.status_code == 200:
    #Merge was successful
    return True
  else:
    #Something went wrong. Oh well.
    return response.status_code

def close(pull):
  url = "https://api.github.com/repos/{}/{}/pulls/{}".format(os.environ.get("GITHUB_USERNAME"), os.environ.get("GITHUB_REPO"), pull['number'])
  payload = {"state" : "closed"}
  response = requests.put(url, auth=get_auth(), data=payload)
  if response.status_code == 200:
    #Close was successful
    return True
  else:
    #Something went wrong. Oh well.
    return response.status_code
```

Now merge works just fine, when I run it with a pull request, the pull request is merged and it feels good.

But close gives me a 404. This is strange since merge can clearly find the pull request, and also shows that I clearly have permissions set up properly so I can close the request.

I have also confirmed that I can close the request manually by logging in on github and pressing the 'close pull request' button.

Why does github give me a 404 for the close function but not the merge function? What is different between these two functions?

Comment: Consider using a library such as https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub or https://github.com/sigmavirus24/github3.py rather than manual requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that the 'update a pull request' api call should be a POST request, not a put request.

Changing

`response = requests.put(url, auth=get_auth(), data=payload)`

to

```
response = requests.post(url, auth=get_auth(), data=payload)
```

Fixed the issue.